# Not in scope: ‘heist’ (I'm not using Lens)

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I have an error in this code in Snap haskell app:

```
import Snap.Http.Server
import Snap.Core
import Snap.Snaplet
import Snap.Snaplet.Heist
import Snap.Util.FileServe
import Snap.Util.GZip
import Heist.Interpreted
import Heist

data App = App { appHeist :: Snaplet (Heist App) }

routes :: [(ByteString, Handler App App ())]
routes = [("", serveDirectory "static")]

appInit :: SnapletInit App App
appInit = makeSnaplet "app" "An snaplet example application." Nothing $ do
    h <- nestSnaplet "" heist $ heistInit "templates"
    addRoutes routes
    return $ App h
```

The error is:

```
Not in scope: ‘heist’
```

and I can't find in what package the function "heist" is.

**Note that I'm not using Lens and don't want to.**
Is there any way not to use them and make my code compile?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Snap or Heist (?) but [Snap itself already depends on lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.14.0.6). If you are using Snap, you are using `lens` - there is no way around this other than to fork the library and modify it to not use `lens`. Furthermore, while many `lens` types are simply type synonyms (so you don't need actually use `lens` to use lenses), `SnapletLens` contains a concrete type from `lens`, meaning you really have to use lens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Snap, but judging from the type signature of `nestSnaplet`, it looks like you're going to need to use a lens of some sort. `nestSnaplet` has the signature

```
nestSnaplet :: ByteString -> SnapletLens v v1 -> SnapletInit b v1-> Initializer b v (Snaplet v1)
```

where `SnapletLens` is just a type synonym for an `Alens` from `lens`.

That also leads me to suspect that `heist` was originally a Template Haskell derived function made using `lens`. Probably what happened is that `App` used to look like this:

```
-- You may need to import Contol.Lens.TH
data App = App { _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App) }
makeLenses ''App
```

which would have made `heist` a lens.

Comment: Note that any `Lens` can function as an `ALens`.

Comment: there's no lens here "https://github.com/cakesolutions/the-pragmatic-haskeller/blob/e1251bfd8ec00d88fd817527db3ed7ad03e14fa6/07-forms/src/Pragmatic/Server/Site.hs"

Comment: It's imported by an `import Pragmatic.Server.Application` statement. If you go to that [file](https://github.com/cakesolutions/the-pragmatic-haskeller/blob/e1251bfd8ec00d88fd817527db3ed7ad03e14fa6/07-forms/src/Pragmatic/Server/Application.hs), you'll see exactly the same pattern of `data Pragmatic = { _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App) ...}` followed by `makeLenses ''Pragmatic`

Comment: Also @OskarK., your hyperlink has an extra quotation mark at the end that makes it 404.

Comment: it complains "Parse error: naked expression at top level" for **makeLenses ''App**

Comment: Assuming you've imported Control.Lens.TH, you'll need to enable Template Haskell. The easiest way is to specify in a pragma at the top of the file `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}`.